# Rails 4 Passing Email To Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to send emails to users who subscribe to other users when they post.

I'm getting an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User with 'id'=272:
```

272 is the id of one of the subscriptions. I'm getting confused with all the moving parts here. How do I pull the subscribers email?

**Posts Controller**

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        @subscribers = current_user.subscribers
        @subscribers.each do |f|
            SubscriptionMailer.send_prayer_request(@post, f).deliver
        end
 [...]
```

**Subscription Mailer**

```
class SubscriptionMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def send_prayer_request(post, subscriber)

    @u = User.find(subscriber)
    mail(   :to => @u.email,
                :from => "services@coprayers.com",
                :subject => "New Post! "
            )
    end

end
```

**User Model**

```
def subscribers
   Subscription.where(subscribe_to_id: self.id)
end
```

**Schema for relevant tables**

```
create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "subscribe_to_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",         default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username",      default: "", null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
end
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@u = User.find(subscriber)` to `@u = User.find(subscriber.user_id)` Otherwise, you are trying to find a user with an ID which matches the subscriber's ID (different from the subscriber's user_id).

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was not far off but nothing I did worked. Still wrapping my head around Rails. :)

Comment: btw love your website as a fellow believer :) GB

Comment: Thanks! Tell your friends. :)